# SwiftUI: How can I increase the area in which a button can be triggered?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How can I increase the area in which a button can be triggered without changing the UI?

This is my code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Text")

            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"))
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading:
                Button(action: { print("add") }) {
                    Image(systemName: SFSymbolName.plus)
                        .font(.system(size: 18))
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For this particular situation, You can add padding to all edges excluding the leading edge **to the `label` of the button**:

```
Button(action: { print("add") }) {
    Text("+")
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 0, bottom: 20, trailing: 50))
}
.background(Color.red) // This is just for seeing the hit area. You should get rid of it
```

**Note that** the maximum tappable area should be inside the rectangle above the title:

[[image: Demo1]

**Also, Note that** only the area **inside** the bar will be tappable. So in the above sample, the overlap of the title and the overlap of the top of the bar will **NOT** be tappable!

Answer (score 2):

The `Button` is as big as it's content. In your case, it is as big as the image. Your button, or the tappable area, is small because the image is just small.

You can contain your image in a bigger `frame`, like this:

```
Button(action: { print("add") }) {
    Image(systemName: SFSymbolName.plus)
        .font(.system(size: 18))
        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
}
```